# Scope.$watch with $timeout

Tags: angularjs

Hey im building functionality in Angular but I have some problems. 
I have ng-model and example-directive, like this.

```js
<input ng-model="model" type="text" class="form-control">
<div example-dir test="model"></div>
```

I want to pass our model from input to directive and each new val from this model start the $timeout, but the first new val should start the $timeout, but the each next new val have to restart our $timeout.

For example. When we pass data to input the $timeout begin start(1000 ms for eaxmple) but the each next data have to restart our $timeout to 0 and begin start again.

There is my directive code:

```js
    function link(scope, element, attr) {
      
        scope.$watch('test',function(nval){
        var timeout;
        function incrementTimer(){
           //some stuff
        }
            if(nval){


                timeout = $timeout(incrementTimer, 1000);
                $timeout.cancel(timeout);

            }
        });
                    
            
    }
```

I dont have idea where and when  pass $timeout and cancel to working corectly.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is redeclaring the `timeout` variable with each iteration. Declare the timeout in the link function, and then just reset it:

```
link: function (scope) {
    function myFunc () { console.log('tick'); }      
    var timeout;

    scope.$watch(function () {
        return scope.test;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (timeout) {
            $timeout.cancel(timeout);
        }
        timeout = $timeout(myFunc, 1000);
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1597/)

Comment: Thanks for amazing simple answer!

Comment: Can you tell me how I can check if scope.$watch value is empty?

Comment: @JanKowalski You have `newVal` and `oldVal`. If you want the updated value check for `if (!newVal) { // value is empty }`